# Slider is not properly configured

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy tratando de modificar un tema de wordpress, pero me he encontrado con un problema el cual no he podido saber la razón. Según la misma documentación, solo es cuestión de activar la opción de **slider**, y decirle que tipo de imágenes con referentes a los post y su categoría.

El tema usando es el siguiente

[Dazzling Theme](https://es-co.wordpress.org/themes/dazzling/)

#### Vista como si fuera un usuario visitando la pagina

[image: imagen 1]

#### Como administrador modificando contenidos y demás

[image: imagen 2]

Cabe resaltar, que estoy trabajando en local, para luego exportar todo a mi servidor remoto, solo espero, que esto no sea uno de los problemas.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta con una captura de la configuración del slider (que es lo que está fallando justamente)? Para hacernos una idea del fallo.

Comment: Pues, pondré una captura de pantalla de la situación, pero no es que ayude mucho.

Comment: @Dr.Manhattan aqui dejare dos enlaces de lo que pides, espero puedas responder, para ver, si no cambio de tema, ya que me urge. [personalizar](https://imgur.com/32mu462), [configuración del silder](https://imgur.com/nrFWep3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tan sencillo como cambiar el número de los sliders a 2 (y luego si quieres a 3 otra vez).
Eso es lo que me funcionó. La categoría dejala a "Sin categoría" si quieres.

[image: Ver imagen]

Comment: Voy a funcionar, al parecer, debo usar solo el numero correcto, y no poner un numero el cual no tengo de artículos.

Comment: Excelente, me funciono muy bien, gracias.